# Unable to execute FOR loop from batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am trying to execute the following command from inside a batch file:

```
@echo off & for /f "delims=*" %A in ('dir /s /b') do echo %~fA %~zA >> "\path\to\output.txt"
```

I found this command from [another thread](https://superuser.com/questions/653860/list-files-recursively-showing-only-full-path-and-file-size-from-windows-command). It prints out the entire file listing along with the file size.

I am able to execute this just fine when pasting into a command line window, but when I throw it into a batch file nothing happens. Am I missing something? Why would this failed when executed from a .bat?

Answer (score 1):

Try `%%`  e.g. `for %%f`  rather than `for %f`,  that might work  In batch files you have to use `for %%f` rather than `for %f`  The `for %f` is only for the command line.  Change all references, so I suppose `%%~zA` rather than `%~zA`

You should really have troubleshooted and tried even a simple for loop, like `for %a in (*.*) do @ECHO %a` you'd then have realized it also worked in command line and not in a batch file and perhaps you'd have found out about the %% requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

> Use **%** when running code from the windows command line.
>
> Use **%%** when running code from the .bat script, inside a file.

Change inside a .bat file:

```
@echo off & for /f "delims=*" %%A in ('dir /s /b') do echo %%~fA %%~zA >> "\path\to\output.txt"
```