# Windows Command Prompt: Display recursive list of files ordered by date with paths

Tags: windows, command-line

What I need: A list of all files in a directory and sub-directories ordered by date and with the date and relative path displayed.

2019-05-20 Topics\File1.txt
2019-05-01 Topics\subfolder\File2.txt
2019-03-03 Topics\File2.txt

The problem: No matter what I try I get the list of files ordered by date **within each directory** (If I could get the date to display at the beginning of a line that would be a bonus).

Topics\File1.txt 2019-05-20
Topics\File2.txt 2019-03-03 *(note: older than file below)*   Topics\subfolder\File2.txt 2019-05-01

---

what I tried:

```
dir d:\topics\*.txt /A:-D /O:-D /s /l | FIND "/"
```

(from [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html): *"To obtain a bare DIR format (no heading or footer info) but retain all the details, pipe the output of DIR into FIND, this assumes that your date separator is / example: DIR c:\temp*. | FIND "/" Normally DIR /b will return just the filename, however when displaying subfolders with DIR /b /s the command **will return a full pathname*** ").

I can't get the path. I tried it with /b and it never gives me the path.

Then I tried most of the solutions found here: [List files recursively showing only full path and file size from Windows Command Prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/653860/list-files-recursively-showing-only-full-path-and-file-size-from-windows-command), including:

```
@echo off & for /f  %A in ('dir /s /b /o:-d') do echo %~fA %~tA >>results.txt
```

and still the results are always listed by date within each directory.

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use PowerShell? This get's you 90% there: `gci -file -recurse | select LastWriteTime, Fullname | sort lastwritetime -Descending`

Comment: you are repeatedly calling `dir` (a utility that focues on a single directory) with a sort operator (so you are telling dir to sort on each invocation), so it makes sense that when you simply concatenate the results of each call that they would be sorted by dir, in the order `for` processed each directory, and that single directories contents would be sorted by date.  In order to achieve what you want, you need to do the sorting at the `for` or `find` level, accumulating all the results before sorting, or perhaps sort the file after you have redirected the output to it.

Comment: perhaps piping through `sort /R` would work for you, though I agree with @KeithMiller.

Comment: I don't think DIR is much use, because while DIR without /b will give the date alongwide the filename,  it won't give the full path of the file alongside filename and date. And DIR with /b will giive you the full path of the file but not with the date. You'd need somethinig to take the output of dir /s (no /b, so you get filename with date), and convert the output to include the full path. Then pipe that to something that can sort by a column of dates. But without the right output which you'd have to derive from DIR ioutput, there's no chance.

Comment: It's possible perhaps for somebody to write something that converts DIR /s output..

Comment: Keith Miller, thank you, that did the trick. 
To others who explained why Dir wasn't going to work, I appreciate the explanation. Thank you.